# NodeJs Error - Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system Expected directory?

Tags: node.js, grpc

I am running my NodeJs App and i am getting an error.

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/node app.js    
    Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
Expected directory: node-v57-linux-x64-glibc
Found: [node-v59-linux-x64-glibc]
This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system
Original error: Cannot find module '/home/projects/kj_app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64-glibc
/grpc_node.node'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/projects/kj_app/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js:53:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/projects/kj_app/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:37:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

**Edit**

```
    sudo /usr/local/bin/npm rebuild

    > protobufjs@6.8.6 postinstall /home/projects/kj_app/node_modules/protobufjs
> node scripts/postinstall
> grpc@1.10.1 install /home/projects/kj_app/node_modules/grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
[grpc] Success: "/home/projects/kj_app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v59-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" al
ready installed
Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile
> @google-cloud/profiler@0.1.14 install /home/projects/kj_app/node_modules/@google-cloud/profiler
> node-gyp rebuild
gyp ERR! clean error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir 'build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.0-6-amd64
gyp ERR! command "/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "
rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/projects/kj_app/node_modules/@google-cloud/profiler
gyp ERR! node -v v9.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @google-cloud/profiler@0.1.14 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @google-cloud/profiler@0.1.14 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-04-10T16_06_40_444Z-debug.log
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run the script with Node 8, but for some reason `npm` thinks it should be installing for Node 9. Also, running these scripts with `sudo` probably isn't helping; you're running in a user directory so you shouldn't need it, and `npm` has some weird behavior when run as root.

Comment: This typically happens when "npm install" is run locally rather than in the container. Any differences, OS, node version become a conflict as constructed grpc module is not built for the right spects. See my comment below for a solution.

Comment: from the functions folder, open command line and enter `npm audit fix`

Answer (score 29):

It seems like you have some verion conflict

```
Expected directory: node-v57-linux-x64-glibc
Found: [node-v59-linux-x64-glibc]
```

Have you tried running [npm rebuild](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/rebuild) in your app folder?

Comment: Maybe this will help: [node-gyp rebuild errors #809](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/809)

Comment: It's funny because just as this page was loading I noticed the suggestion in the console logs to run npm rebuild. Hopefully most folks just aren't getting here because they read the output :-D

Answer (score 19):

**npm rebuild** worked for me :)

Thanx to everyone who replied

(Using **[n](https://github.com/tj/n)** with node **v8.15.1** and npm **6.4.1**)

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem (using nvm) and found that my selected node version was different than the one in `.nvmrc`. I did the following steps to fix it:

```
rm -rf node_modules
nvm use
yarn
```

I removed node_modules because it might have installed a version of some dependencies for the wrong version of node, so I want to ensure I have the correct libraries for the selected version.

When I do `nvm use`, it picks the version of node from the `.nvmrc` in my project.

You can use `npm install` instead of `yarn`. That's just how my project is set up.

Comment: Solved my problem that happened after changing `.nvmrc` files. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem with Google Cloud Functions and Emulator, after migration from node 6 to node 8.

My Solution:

1. `npm rebuild` // no effect
2. delete **node_modules** folder in the **functions** folder
3. `npm install`
4. in the **functions** folder call: `npm i --save firebase-functions`
5. `firebase serve` // start the emulator and try

Answer (score 7):

By any chance did you do a `npm install` in your local (`node-v59`) when it should have been done on the container (`node-v57`)? The grpc binary is for the wrong version of node thus the error. In the case of the question, it looks like a local Mac (OSX - a flavour of Linux) running linux in a Docker container.

```
Expected directory: node-v57-linux-x64-glibc
Found: [node-v59-linux-x64-glibc]
```

The solution would be to `rm -fr node_modules` and do `npm install` **in the container**.

Answer (score 6):

Tried `npm rebuild` and it didn't work for me, what worked is deleting the `node_modules` and the `package-lock.json`, and re install node packages using `npm install`

Answer (score 3):

After trying many things I ended up doing the following (based on other answer):

1. Updated node to latest version
2. Updated npm to latest version
3. npm rebuild on the project

Answer (score 3):

No other answer worked for me. Eventually I fixed it by using the [@grpc/grpc-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@grpc/grpc-js) package instead of [grpc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grpc)

So I've just did

```
yarn remove grpc
yarn add @grpc/grpc-js
```

and changed all imports:

```js
# before
import something from 'grpc'
# after
import something from '@grpc/grpc-js'
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem (but on the frontend, with Jest, Firebase and NVM). So this might not directly solve the original question but might help others who came here.

### Check versions

Try to call these and see if **node versions in the paths match**:

```
which node
which npm
```

In my case also:

```
which firebase
```

### Webstorm

In my case, I ran into this problem when using Webstorm, Jest, and Firebase, and I wanted to run the tests using Webstorm's tools.

It was a problem with my "Jest Run Configuration". It pointed to **a different version of Node** than I was using as a default for the system.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and none of these solutions worked for me. For anyone having a similar lack of success, a more aggressive `npm rebuild` to force the correct version did it for me: `npm rebuild --target=8.15.1 --target_platform=linux --target_arch=x64 --target_libc=glibc` (where 8.15.1 is the node version you are using - I believe this is the version used in the original question).

Answer (score 0):

following command worked for me
`npm rebuild --unsafe-perm --build-from-source`
Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/blockchain-cloud/user/use-hyperledger-fabric-sdks-develop-applications.html#GUID-59A8279E-7A90-4823-9538-EA236BF9D164

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I've installed grpc via `yarn add grpc` on my local machine.

But my code was running inside a Docker container, which had a different node version.

So before my `docker-compose.yaml` looked like

```yaml
services:
  server:
    image: node:lts-alpine
    container_name: repro_server
    volumes:
      - ./package.json:/package.json
      - ./yarn.lock:/yarn.lock
      - ./tsconfig.json:/tsconfig.json
      - ./node_modules:/node_modules
      - ./index.ts:/index.ts
    command: yarn run ts-node-dev index
```

Note, that I was using `node_modules` from my local machine. The simple fix was to install the `node_modules` inside the container:

```
services:
  server:
    image: node:lts-alpine
    container_name: repro_server
    volumes:
      - ./package.json:/package.json
      - ./yarn.lock:/yarn.lock
      - ./tsconfig.json:/tsconfig.json
      - ./index.ts:/index.ts
    entrypoint: sh -c "yarn install --frozen-lockfile && yarn run ts-node-dev index"
```

*Thanks to [thesayyn](https://github.com/thesayyn) for helping my with this issue!*

Answer (score 0):

***Solved:***  After spending a lot of time over this issue, I found the solution and it's tested as well. Just run the below command after install all the required packages along-with grpc.

For Linux & MAC:

```
sudo npm rebuild --target=8.1.0 --target_platform=linux --target_arch=x64 --target_libc=glibc --update-binary
```

For Windows:

```
npm rebuild --target=8.1.0 --target_platform=linux --target_arch=x64 --target_libc=glibc --update-binary
```