# Error with Firebase on Electron app: Failed to load gRPC

Tags: firebase, electron, google-cloud-firestore, grpc, firebase-admin

I'm building an Electron app, and in the renderer.js file, I'm using Firebase Admin to get Firestore data. However, whenever I run it, it returns this error in the logs..

```
Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
Expected directory: electron-v2.0-darwin-x64-unknown
Found: [node-v48-darwin-x64-unknown]
This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system
```

I tried to run "npm rebuild", but it still didn't fix it.
I also tried updating Firebase Admin and gRPC.

Here is the code from the renderer.js file...

```
// This file is required by the index.html file and will
// be executed in the renderer process for that window.
// All of the Node.js APIs are available in this process.

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require('./credentials.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://mytestapp.firebaseio.com"
});

var db = admin.firestore();
const settings = {
  timestampsInSnapshots: true
};
db.settings(settings);

function LoadList() {

  db.collection("Orders").get().then(function(Collection){

    Collection.forEach(function(OrderDoc){
      console.log(OrderDoc.id)
    })

  }).catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
  });

}

document.querySelector('#ListSec').addEventListener('click', LoadOrderList)
```

Any ideas? I've been trying to solve this for hours, but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJs Error - Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system Expected directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758008/nodejs-error-failed-to-load-grpc-binary-module-because-it-was-not-installed-fo)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That error message indicates that gRPC was installed for Node, not for Electron. Electron has a different binary interface, so binary modules like gRPC need to be installed specifically for Electron. You can generally do this just by running `npm rebuild --runtime=electron --target=2.0.0` (modified to match the version of Electron you want to use).

Comment: is there an automated way to `npm install` while avoiding this problem?

Comment: You could put the command I suggested in your installation script. Or maybe as a `postinstall` script/hook in your own `package.json` file.

Answer (score 3):

The original answer by @murgatroid99 was helpful at the time, and a postinstall command worked great up until electron v7, where the issue returned.

For anyone else who comes across this issue, I've found a better solution:

#### the [electron-rebuild](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-rebuild) package

```sh
npm install electron-rebuild --save-dev
```

Run it using

```
npx electron-rebuild
```

Or, add it as a postinstall command

```sh
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "electron-rebuild"
  },
  ...
}
```

Further information is in the official [Electron Documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules#installing-modules-and-rebuilding-for-electron)