# "Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system" Only on windows

Tags: npm, electron

I am having above error when I am trying to run my packaged app on windows. It works perfectly fine on linux.

```
Expected directory: electron-v2.0-win32-ia32-unknown
Found: node-v57-linux-x64-glibc
```

This is where expected directory was supposed to be:

```
"/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node"
```

package.json

```
    "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^2.0.10",
    "firebase": "^5.5.2",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-packager": "^12.2.0",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.8.2"
  }
```

Things I tried:

- Rebuid
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758008/nodejs-error-failed-to-load-grpc-binary-module-because-it-was-not-installed-fo)

Let me know if you need any other detail.

Answer (score 5):

You have to rebuild the package in your Electron's version.
For example, here is the command I use to rebuild my C++ package for my Electron App :

```
npm rebuild --runtime=electron --target=2.0.11 --disturl=https://atom.io/download/electron --abi=57
```

You have to say to npm rebuild the runtime (electron in this case), the version target you want (2.0.11 in my case), the disturl is used to download Electron release and finally the ABI of your Electron's version (you can get this with this command: electron --abi)

Hope this can help you :)

**[EDIT]**

Here the command to have ABI version with Electron installed in global:
[image: Screenshot Electron]

Or here when I want the Electron's version & ABI installed in my project:
[image: Screenshot Electron]

Comment: If you don't have Electron installed in global, it's normal, so use "npx electron --abi" in your project with Electron, or install it in global "npm i -g electron"

Comment: For the Electron v2.0, its ABI is 57

Comment: I now get Found: [electron-v3.0-linux-x64-glibc,node-v64-linux-x64-glibc]. I removed node_modules and install 3.0.10 this time.

Comment: Took me hours to find this. Thank you!!