# Firebase CLI Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-cli

I followed the instructions on the [Firebase Website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#npm) but I do the `npm install`, I login and then I do `firebase serve` and receive the following error.

> Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
>   Expected directory: node-v57-darwin-x64-unknown
>   Found: [node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown]
>   This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system

I have tried suggestions such as running `npm rebuild`, and deleting the `node_modules` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52945122) however the problem still persists. Any Ideas of what can be done to fix this. I've been using firebase for a while and only recently have I been encountering problems like this thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

open a terminal / command prompt / CLI from your `functions` folder and issue the following command:

```
npm audit fix
```

Comment: I'm buying you a beer, found this after hours of headache - thanks!