# Getting error when deploying a Google Cloud Function after Node upgrade

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I updated `Brew` then updated `Node` from `10.12.0 -> 13.8.0`

Now, I get the following error when trying to deploy a Google Cloud Function

```
firebase deploy --only functions:createJWT
```

> i  functions: preparing functions directory for
>   uploading...
>
> Error: Error parsing triggers: Failed to load gRPC binary module
>   because it was not installed for the current system Expected
>   directory: node-v79-darwin-x64-unknown Found:
>   [node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown] This problem can often be fixed by
>   running "npm rebuild" on the current system Original error: Cannot
>   find module
>   '/Users/.../cloud-functions/functions/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v79-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node'
>   Require stack:
>   - /Users/.../cloud-functions/functions/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js
>   - /Users/.../cloud-functions/functions/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js
>   - /Users/.../cloud-functions/functions/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js
>   - /Users/.../cloud-functions/functions/node_modules/grpc/index.js
>   - /Users/.../cloud-functions/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/common-grpc/src/service.js
>   - /Users/.../cloud-functions/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/common-grpc/src/operation.js
>   - /Users/.../cloud-functions/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/common-grpc/src/index.js
>   - /Users/.../cloud-functions/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/logging/src/index.js
>   - /Users/.../cloud-functions/functions/index.js
>   - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js
>
> Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before
>   deploying.

Tried `npm rebuild` and `npm install` in my functions directory and nothing works

Furthermore...could this issue be due to the fact that GCF Node runtime enviroment is Node10 and I have installed Node13 on my machine? - according to these docs:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-10-runtime

I am struggling to revert back to Node10, have tried by running `brew install node@10` and get this:

[image]

Then tried running the following command as per output above to symlink it to `/usr/local` but still no luck

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 1):

Searching around about this error, indeed, this seems that the problem is related to your system waiting for a version and founding another one - as per this part of the error.

> Error: Error parsing triggers: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system Expected directory: node-v79-darwin-x64-unknown Found: [node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown]

There are some options that you can give it a try, besides trying the `npm rebuild`. Another option might be updating the `package.json` - as per this case solved [here](https://support.glitch.com/t/getting-grpc-error-all-of-a-sudden/6422/4) - that would return your npm version to an old one.

Besides that, on this question in the Community, there are a few solutions that helped other users, that I would recommend you to take a look at it: [NodeJs Error - Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system Expected directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758008/nodejs-error-failed-to-load-grpc-binary-module-because-it-was-not-installed-fo)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: my `package.json` specifies `"node": "10"` if I change to `12` I get `Error: The only valid choices are: {"node": "8"} and {"node": "10"}` when I run `firebase deploy functions`....so correct me if my thinking is wrong, my machine has `node 13.8` and trying to deploy to `node10` Google env doesnt like it?

Comment: Hi, @Roggie checking the official documentation, it seems that [Node.js 8](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-8-runtime) is supported and  [Node.js 10](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-10-runtime) is still in Beta. This confirms that indeed, Cloud Functions don't support Node.js 13 is supported yet. I would recommend you to raise a feature request for it [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers), for this to be checked by Google.

Comment: yes, trying to deploy from a higher version was the issue, going back to `node10.19.0` worked.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for confirming that, @Roggie!

Comment: @Roggie Please, consider accepting or upvoting my answer, if you think it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Trying to deploy to an unsupported Google Function execution environment won't work. According to the google [docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec) the current supported environments are `Node8` and `Node10(beta)`, re-installing `Node10` worked for me.